# Android: Physical Back button returning to restricted activity

Tags: android, security

I have an admin activity in an app which will allow him or her make changes to certain things. How do I prevent a normal user from pressing the "back" button from entering this activity?

Comment: If a normal user cannot get into the activity to begin with, how does the back button get there?

Comment: To get into the admin page a user has to enter a password. However if the admin returns to the main page a normal user can press the back button to return to the previous activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can launch the `Activity` with the [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY) flag and that should keep it out of the backstack.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend putting some kind of user validation in the admin activity, which will disable the normal layout and display some kind of message that tells the user they are not allowed to make changes.